# Is it possible to customize \autocite and \autocite* to behave differently in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I was wondering if it is possible to customize `\autocite` and `\autocite*` to behave differently, say `\autocite` works as `\supercite` while `\autocite*` as `\textcite`.

UPDATE:

After Moewe's answer, `\autocite` works as `\supercite`. Then I copied my old customization of `\supercite` to show the superscript number in `[]`, see the `\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}...` part in the MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}


%%%% This is my customization of supercite
%%%% and it causes error
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}
  \bibopenbracket}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\bibclosebracket}



\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\autocite}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\textcite}
    {\supercite}}
\renewcommand*{\autocites}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\textcites}
    {\supercites}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite*{sigfridsson}.

Lorem \autocites{sigfridsson}{worman} ipsum \autocites*{sigfridsson}{worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Since `\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}...` works as expected when there is no

```
\renewcommand*{\autocite}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\textcite}
    {\supercite}}
```

I made this updating instead of a new question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please  give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. It is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: The error message you get is `Error: Bibliography macro 'cite:init' undefined.` The definition of `\supercite` looks as though it comes from `numeric-comp.cbx` and not `numeric.cbx`, which* the example is using. Try switching from `style=numeric,` to `style=numeric-comp,`.

Comment: BTW: The same issue can be reproduced in the MWE by calling `\supercite` instead of `\autocite` directly showing that the issue is unrelated to the redefinition of `\autocite`.

Comment: Oops, I must had made some mistakes last night. `style=numeric-comp` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to define starred and unstarred versions of `\...cite` commands defined with `\DeclareCiteCommand` differently. The unstarred version is defined with `\DeclareCiteCommand{\jiewuzacite}`, the starred version with `\DeclareCiteCommand*{\jiewuzacite}`.

As far as I can see, however, it is not easily possible to do the same for multicite commands. That is to say, you can define `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\jiewuzacites}[<wrapper>]{\jiewuzacite}{\multicitedelim}`, but you can not easily change the wrapper based on whether there is a star or not with this interface.
For `\autocite` that implies that `\autocite`/`\autocite*` will work exactly as expected, but `\autocites`/`\autocites*` will not.

If you think the starred versions need an independent `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand`, please open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. At the moment I think it is a good thing that `biblatex` enforces consistency between the starred and unstarred version. Indeed, I believe that using two so different citation commands (which need very different grammatical structures to fit into a sentence) as the starred and unstarred version of the same base-macro name is a bit risky...

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
% copy of \supercite from numeric.cbx
\DeclareCiteCommand{\jiewuzacite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}

% copy of \textcite from numeric.cbx
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\jiewuzacite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{jiewuza}{\jiewuzacite}{\jiewuzacite}
% we can't have different wrappers for starred/unstarred versions
% for the multicite commands, so re-use the single cite as
% multicite command ...   

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=jiewuza}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite*{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you can completely bypass `biblatex`'s relevant commands here and implement `\autocite` yourself.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\autocite}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\textcite}
    {\supercite}}
\renewcommand*{\autocites}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\textcites}
    {\supercites}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite*{sigfridsson}.

Lorem \autocites{sigfridsson}{worman} ipsum \autocites*{sigfridsson}{worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

should do it and will work for `\autocite` and `\autocites`.

In general I would recommend against redefining `\...cite` commands controlled by `biblatex` with anything other than the official interface and you are more or less on your own if something breaks, but it might be the simplest solution here. It should be noted that you do lose the `autopunct` feature of `\autocite` here, which may or may not be relevant for you. In newer versions of `biblatex`, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/733 and related posts might help there.

Comment: You are thoughtful. I like the alternative way. I tried to make `\supercite` and `\textcite` show superscript number in `[]`. So I added `\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init} 
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}} 
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}
  \bibopenbracket} 
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex} 
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\bibclosebracket}
` Then it reports error.

Comment: @jiewuza I suggest you as a new question about that with an MWE. The answer will depend on the style you use.

Comment: Since my customization is closely related to this question, I updated instead of asking a new question. Check my updating of my original question.